# Is it confusing if I use both Section and Article on the same page?

Tags: html

From what I understand, article is for a standalone content,section can be used to group a list of articles or can be used inside article to represent parts.
When implement this idea, I've got a case:
A page with main content being an article. After the article tag, I want to load a forum topic with all its replies. Each topic and reply is using article tag.
My question is-- Will it be confusing for assistive technology if I group the topic and its replies inside Section tag? The mark up look like this:

```
<div id="page">
  <article role="main"> main content</article>
  <section id="forum">
           <article>topic content</article>
            <article>reply-1</article>
            <article>reply-2</article>
  </section>
</div>
```

if the above markup can't provide an easy way for the assistive technology to understand the topic section is connected to the main content, what markup would you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case i would almost certainly do it this way

```
<div id="page">
    <article role="main">
        <section id="main">
            main content
        </section>
        <section id="forum">
            topic content
            <ul class="comments">
                <li>reply-1</li>
                <li>reply-2</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

Purely on the basis that you have an article, and within that article you have appear to have 2 sections, 1 for the main content, and 1 for the forum content.
within the forum content, you also have a list of comments.

To me anyway, this seems like the correct semantic way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them where ever you want. Their use is semantic. If you think it makes more sense to layout your code like that then do it.

However, most people will say that sections should be inside articles unless there are no articles.

I would consider using the header tag for the first article tag. Then make the section an article and the articles sections. Then put the header inside the article.

```
<div id="page">
  <article id="forum">
      <header role="main"> main content</header>
            <section>topic content</section>
            <section>reply-1</section>
            <section>reply-2</section>
  </article>
</div>
```

It is really just a matter of opinion, however, we don't yet know how google and other search providers will treat these. The idea is to give your code the same modular look that the layout has.

Comment: I never really think about how the search engines will treat them. I build and use the tags how they are specified to be used by the W3C, and how they would fit in any publication. I would like to optimistically assume that search engines 'should' eventually treat them in the way that they are defined. But it doesn't unduly concern me, as I know that the page is structured more-or-less correctly. (but you are correct, they can be used how you feel they should be used)

Comment: Yes. I agree. BTW I upped your answer because it was better then mine.